# Select Last N documents of all Users in MongoDB Collection using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm having a MongoDB Collection, I need to Select Last 3 documents (Order By Descending LastUpdate) of Each Employee (Emp_ID) using C# MongoDB Query.

The Sample Collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575f4e2efd14481598fc0ebf"),
    "Emp_ID" : "100",
    "LastUpdate" : ISODate("2016-06-13T18:30:00.000Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575f4e2efd14481598fc0ec0"),
    "Emp_ID" : "101",
    "LastUpdate" : ISODate("2016-06-14T06:33:12.000Z")
}
,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575f4e2efd14481598fc0ec1"),
    "Emp_ID" : "101",
    "LastUpdate" : ISODate("2016-06-14T06:33:16.000Z")
}
,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575f4e2efd14481598fc0ec2"),
    "Emp_ID" : "102",
    "LastUpdate" : ISODate("2016-06-14T06:33:18.000Z")
}
,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575f4e2efd14481598fc0ec3"),
    "Emp_ID" : "100",
    "LastUpdate" : ISODate("2016-06-14T06:33:26.000Z")
}
,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575f4e2efd14481598fc0ec3"),
    "Emp_ID" : "102",
    "LastUpdate" : ISODate("2016-06-14T06:33:29.000Z")
}
,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575f4e2efd14481598fc0ec4"),
    "Emp_ID" : "101",
    "LastUpdate" : ISODate("2016-06-14T06:34:18.000Z")
}
,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575f4e2efd14481598fc0ec5"),
    "Emp_ID" : "102",
    "LastUpdate" : ISODate("2016-06-14T06:34:20.000Z")
}
,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575f4e2efd14481598fc0ec6"),
    "Emp_ID" : "100",
    "LastUpdate" : ISODate("2016-06-14T06:34:31.000Z")
}
,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575f4e2efd14481598fc0ec7"),
    "Emp_ID" : "102",
    "LastUpdate" : ISODate("2016-06-14T06:34:35.000Z")
}
,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575f4e2efd14481598fc0ec8"),
    "Emp_ID" : "101",
    "LastUpdate" : ISODate("2016-06-14T06:34:38.000Z")
}
```

I know to select a single Employee info

The Experimental Query:

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<Employee>("EmpInfo");
var filterBuilder = Builders<Employee>.Filter;
var filter = filterBuilder.Eq("Emp_ID", "100");
var Item = collection.Find(filter)
                     .Sort(Builders<Employee>.Sort.Descending("LastUpdate"))
                     .Limit(3).ToList();
```

Kindly assist me, how to Select last 3 records of every employee from the above collection using C# MongoDB Query (I'm preferring single query execution).

Comment: Have you tried with aggregate? that's what you'd need for all the employees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice example of data usage!

To get that we need to use aggregation, `$match` - limits number of elements taken in to action by date, then `$sort` sorts our data by descending date value, `$group` - groups records by employee ID, and finally `$project` slices array of results and gives us only three firs positions.

`startDate` is used just as a data limiter - but in real life you should use it too :-)

```
    startDate = new Date() // Current date
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 7) // Subtract 7 days


    db.irpunch.aggregate([{
                $match : {
                    LastUpdate : {
                        $gte : startDate
                    }
                }
            }, {
                $sort : {
                    LastUpdate : -1
                }
            }, //sort data
            {
                $group : {
                    _id : "$Emp_ID",
                    documents : {
                        $push : "$$ROOT"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                $project : {
                    _id : 1,
                    documents : {
                        $slice : ["$documents", 3]
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
```

***EDIT***

```
public static void Main()
{
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    var database = client.GetDatabase("test");

    var collection = database.GetCollection<InnerDocument>("irpunch");


    var aggregationDocument = collection.Aggregate()
        .Match(x=>x.LastUpdate> DateTime.Now.AddDays(-40))
        .SortByDescending(x => x.LastUpdate)
        .Group(BsonDocument.Parse("{ _id:'$Emp_ID', documents:{ '$push':'$$ROOT'}}"))
        .Project<AggregationResult>(BsonDocument.Parse("{ _id:1, documents:{ $slice:['$documents', 3]}}")).ToList()
        ;

    foreach (var aggregationResult in aggregationDocument)
    {
        foreach (var innerDocument in aggregationResult.documents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"empID: {aggregationResult._id}, doc date: {innerDocument.LastUpdate}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}


public class AggregationResult
{
    public int _id { get; set; }
    public InnerDocument[] documents { get; set; }
}

public class InnerDocument
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Emp_ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wow! at one point after commenting I had gotten stuck too. You're awesome

Comment: Can you please translate this into C#.

Comment: Will try tonight :)

Comment: @IRPunch added c# version :-)